# Is a character that had their brain devoured by an Intellect devourer dead? Can they be raised?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, character-death

Inspired by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/95270/11402).

Is a character that is currently the host of a brain devourer, *body thief* style, dead? Can they be raised, resurrected?

If yes, do I have to kill the intellect devourer first?

Comment: [Related] [What happens when a creature possessed by an intellect devourer is true polymorphed?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87319)

Answer (score 29):

A character who is the host of an intellect devourer is definitely *not* dead.

> If the host body drops to 0 hit points, the intellect devourer must leave it. A *protection from good and evil* spell cast on the body drives the intellect devourer out. The intellect devourer is also forced out if the target regains its devoured brain by means of a *wish*. By spending 5 feet of its movement, the intellect devourer can voluntarily leave the body, teleporting to the nearest unoccupied space within 5 feet of it. **The body then dies**, unless its brain is restored wthin 1 round.

As they're not dead, they can't be resurrected. If you want to resurrect the body, you have to kill it first - of course, driving the intellect devourer out will kill it within 6 seconds anyway.

Even once you've killed them, a *revifiy* spell will not restore the missing brain, so, while it's not specified, the body will probably just die again. A *raise dead* spell won't even work - if the body is missing any important parts, *raise dead* just fails. On the other hand, a *resurrection* spell or a *true resurrection* spell will restore the brain, as will *reincarnate*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54037/discussion-on-answer-by-miniman-is-a-character-that-had-their-brain-devoured-by).

Comment: All of this on a CR2 monster :(

Comment: So... leads to even wackier questions.  Could you reincarnate them, revivify the body, and have the intellect devourer hop in and take up residence before it dies again?  Also, if they're not dead, then Clone won't trigger.

Comment: @BenBarden To the first, there are no rules covering this situation, so it's up to the DM. To the second, who said anything about Clone?

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround not needing the *Wish* spell is that, since the victim is not yet dead, you may *not* want to kill or drive out the Intellect Devourer first.  Paralyze or Petrify or otherwise render the Intellect Devourer unable to act.  Then cast Regenerate on the victim to regrow his brain.  *Then* kill or drive out the Intellect Devourer.